# Replacing layout with another in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have an app where user can change the content of the layout by pressing a button but when i want to replace a layout i get error in replacement line:

[image]

This is `addtotry.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#e7e7e7"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="adrese"
                android:id="@+id/adreseButton"
                android:layout_below="@+id/infoButton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="350px"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:id="@+id/imageLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="350px"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/imageview"/>
            </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageLayout"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtotry);

        Button btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adreseButton);

        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentVieta fh = new FragmentVieta();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fh);
                ft.commit();



            }
        });

    }
}
```

I do not now where i have made mistake because i have created FragmentView and it extends fragment. Do you have any idea how to fix my problem which is shown in picture? Because i changed to (int, com.wunderlist.slidinglayersample) and it said expression needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your `FragmentVieta` extends android.app.Fragment or support one ?
As you are using `getFragmentManager()` the `FragmentVieta` must extend from `android.app.Fragment` only.

Comment: as i said FragmentVieta extends Fragment

Comment: is it `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` ?